# concentrate image path with binded angularjs item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<img class="upload-photo" src="images/uploaded + {{img}}" />
```

this doesn't work. I also tried `{{images/uploaded + img}}` but no luck. images/uploaded is my folder path

Comment: Se browser developer console, for the request path. Also use `ng-src="'images\uploaded'+img"` for better handling of expression

Comment: I think you are looking for ng-src

Comment: @Chandermani my {{img}} value is like img.png, should I use ng-src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the expression for src should be

`src="{{'images/uploaded' + img}}"`

Also it would be better to use `ng-src`

`ng-src="'images\uploaded'+img"`